# Okular - Can't add to GNOME taskbar

Tags: gnome, okular, favorites

I can't seem to add Okular pdf reader to my GNOME taskbar. Every other program I can "add to favorites" and it shows up on the taskbar. Not Okular. It's the sole KDE program I use, does that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of August 2017, this is still an issue.

You can workaround it without interfering with the package manager like this:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/org.kde.okular.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/okular.desktop
```

Comment: Now we end up with having 2 desktop icons...

Comment: A better solution would be to add to favorites from the omnibar as shown in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223635/1375202)

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled about this issue too. Seems this is because of a (seemingly stupid) limitation in the gnome shell:

As pointed out in [this answer on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59654/19705), gnome shell expects the desktop file to be named exactly like the command for the "Add to Favorites" to work. I consider this a bug (since for all kde applications, the .desktop file typically is named like org.kde.appname.desktop; gnome shell should definitely be able to favorite kde apps; and gnome can't expect to change kde's desktop file naming scheme just because they cannot handle arbitrary desktop file names).

As a workaround (though this might interfer with the automatic package management), you could rename the desktop file to the name that gnome-shell expects:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/applications/org.kde.okular.desktop /usr/share/applications/okular.desktop
```

This works on my system - but I have to say I'm not running Ubuntu at the moment but arch linux.