# Multiple "Dolphin File Manager" icons in dock on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dolphin

In Ubuntu 19.04 GNOME, when I click icon for the Dolphin file manager in the dock, it always makes a new icon:

[image: screenshot showing multiple icons]

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: @pomsky it maybe related to dolphin being a qt app. See the bug links provided by N0rbert [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166189/248158). Some qt apps, but not all, currently don't behave well with the launcher.

Comment: @DKBose Maybe, but these two sound like different issues ("cannot add to favourites" vs "multiple icons after launching the app"). I cannot see a `StartupWMClass` entry in any of the `.desktop` launchers for the applications [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1166171/480481) btw.

Comment: @pomsky [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738672) mentions StartupWMClass. I'll give it a try later. But there are qt apps without `StartupWMClass` in their .desktop files that seem to work well enough in the Ubuntu dock.

Comment: @DKBose Sorry, my previous comment was probably not very clear. `StartupWMClass` is *not* supposed to fix the "cannot add to favourites" problem, but rather it should be tried to fix the "multiple icons after launching the app" (the issue raised in this current question), I noticed the `StartupWMClass` entry was missing in the `.desktop` files in your question. Assuming those were the system-generated default `.desktop` files, it's worth a shot to try the `StartupWMClass` fix to solve the "multiple icons" issue, it worked many times before.

Comment: @pomsky, yes they were system-generated. All I did was to remove the multiple translations.