# Ubuntu 18.04 always shown seperate taskbar icon for Kate editor

Tags: 18.04, icons, taskbar, kate

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Hello all:
I'm using my favorite Kate editor in Ubuntu 18.04. I've pin the icon to the taskbar using "Show Applications" -> search "kate" -> (right click) "add to favorites".
Whenever I launch Kate editor, a separate but identical Kate icon will appear on the task bar, with a little orange arrow showing on the left side indicating it's currently running. However, the original pinned icon of kate is still there and not showing running status.
OTOH, other applications like terminal or system monitor simply shows a little orange running indicating arrow next to its original icon.
The problem with duplicate icon is I always accidentally click the kate icon again, causing Kate to ask me if I want to keep existing work, and sometimes mess up my working session if I'm not careful.

I know this is a really small thing, but it is really annoying to me. Is there anyway to avoid problem?

[image: picture to the kate icon problem]

Edit:
I'm not sure if this is a related question and if it helps with debug the issue? [Ubuntu 18.04: "Add to Favorites" missing for certain qt-based applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166171/ubuntu-18-04-add-to-favorites-missing-for-certain-qt-based-applications)

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 I also now see that issue, I had not noticed before. Right clicking on the default non active Kate icon I get on clicking show details
unable to find "org.kde.kate.desktop". it still starts kate for me though.
found this link..which didnt work no matter =kate, "kate" , "kate, kate" or Kates or "kate, Kate" 
https://beamtic.com/duplicated-icons-in-launcher

Comment: spent 2  hours on this problem I have which I had not noticed until now... Ive tried adding WM_CLASS(STRING)=kate to the .desktop files (there are a few, for instance one for my kate startup in HOME/.config/autostart and another in HOME/.local/share/applications . It might just be that kate is not compliant as other programs are. I do have a parameter -s mySession but I dont think that is the problem. I will just have to live with it. some links that might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795622/how-do-i-set-the-the-app-name-of-the-wm-class-string-of-a-tkinter-window

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-does-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file-represent

https://beamtic.com/duplicated-icons-in-launcher


I also tried -DBUS-StartupType=multi changed to =unique, even tried to convert "kate" to Latin1   and "Kate" and "kate", "Kate" and "kate", "kate" and "kate, myKate" ... myKate being the session name.

all to no avail.