# How to remove duplicate app in recommended apps?

Tags: 20.04

When I try to open a file with another application it shows two KolourPaint apps. How can I remove the one without the icon?

[image]

Comment: It probably means that you've got two versions of the app installed... a .deb version, and a snap version. Determine which is the most current version. `dpkg -l *olour* | grep ii` may help. If they're both the same, then delete the snap version. do `snap list` and `snap remove`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to open a terminal and run

```
sudo rm /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/kolourpaint_org.kde.kolourpaint.desktop
```

[image: Only one Kolourpaint icon]

Note:

- Make sure there's no version of `kolourpaint_org.kde.kolourpaint.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`
- You'll need to do this each time this particular snap is updated or until [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420694) is fixed.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully it gets fixed.