# Cannot add gitkraken as favorite

Tags: favorites

When I right-click the icon of `gitkraken` in the taskbar and select "Add to favorires" nothing happens; it stays where it is and doesn't move.  (The article [Okular - Can't add to GNOME taskbar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917252/okular-cant-add-to-gnome-taskbar) may be related but this seems different.)

I'm running Ubuntu 21.10 and gitkraken was installed via `sudo apt install gitkraken-amd64.deb`.

Finding the executable:

```
~$ which gitkraken
/usr/bin/gitkraken
~$ ls -al /usr/bin/gitkraken
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Mar  4 08:42 /usr/bin/gitkraken -> /usr/share/gitkraken/resources/bin/gitkraken.sh
```

The script `gitkraken.sh` figures out where it is living and results in executing `/usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken` shown below:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 140259960 Mar  4 08:42 gitkraken
```

Under `/usr/share/applications` the name is the same:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   289 Mar  4 08:42 gitkraken.desktop
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   314 Mar  4 08:42 gitkraken-url-handler.desktop
```

UPDATE:  I found that the article [Cannot add custom launcher to Ubuntu Dock ('Add to Favorites' option does not show up)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990833/cannot-add-custom-launcher-to-ubuntu-dock-add-to-favorites-option-does-not-sh?rq=1) worked to add the icon to favorites.

However, when it runs, it shows the activation icon back in the task bar; i.e., rather than showing the "activation dot" on the icon in the favorites, it adds an icon in the task bar with the "activation dot".  So, not ideal.

I tried changing the symlink to point at the executable directly rather than the script but that didn't improve anything; same behavior.

So, I'd still like to understand why the "Add to favorites" doesn't work from the menu.  Is it of invoking the gitkraken.sh which then invokes gitkraken executable?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I migrated to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I see the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @Arxeiss No, the only thing I found was using snap or flatpack worked.

Answer (score 0):

Same with Studio 3T: it seems like a problem with it being installed externally.

Same after update on ubuntu 22.04 lts